# Exists an $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi: M \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varphi(m) \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module with some torsion element $m$. Does there exist an $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi: M \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varphi(m) \neq 0$?

Comment: How is $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ supposed to be a $R$-module?

Comment: If you only want to have a homomorphism of abelian groups, this is certainly true, since $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is an injective object, hence a non-zero map $\langle m \rangle \to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ extends to a map $M \to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MooS The relevant property is that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a cogenerator. Of course if $m$ is a torsion element of a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, there is a nonzero morphism $\langle m\rangle\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (which can so be extended because of injectivity), but this is part of the proof that the object is a cogenerator.

Comment: Yes, 'cogenerator' is the name for such an object. Nevertheless to prove this, injectivity is the key property. (I am aware that $\mathbb Q$ is also injective, but not a cogenerator...)